# Para que serve o modificador volatile do C/C++?

Tags: c, c++, volatile

Tenho visto em alguns códigos em **C/C++** declarações como esta:

```
volatile int i = 0;
```

Gostaria de saber para que serve o modificador `volatile` e em que casos devo usá-lo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Uma variável `volatile` indica ao compilador que a variável pode ser modificada sem o conhecimento do programa principal. Dessa forma, o compilador não pode prever com segurança se pode otimizar trechos de programa onde esta variável se encontra.

Por exemplo:

```
int x = 100;

while(x == 100)
{
// codigo
}
```

Nesse caso, o compilador verificará que pode fazer essa otimização, pois o valor de `x` nunca é alterado:

```
while(true)
{
// codigo
}
```

O que pode ser visto no `assembly` gerado:

```
$LL2@main:   
    jmp SHORT $LL2@main
```

Enquanto, usando `volatile`, essa otimização não é feita.

```
volatile int x = 100;

while(x == 100)
{
// codigo
}
```

Como pode ser visto no `assembly` gerado:

```
$LL2@main:
    cmp DWORD PTR _x$[ebp], 100
    je  SHORT $LL2@main
```

Answer (score 7):

Uma variável ou objeto declarado [`volatile`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable) impede o compilador de realizar a otimização no código envolvendo objetos voláteis, garantindo assim que cada atribuição de variável volátil ler o acesso de memória correspondente.

Sem a palavra-chave `volatile`, o compilador sabe se tal variável não precisa ser relida a partir da memória em cada uso, pois não deve haver qualquer gravações ao seu local de memória de qualquer outro processo ou segmento.

De acordo com o [`C++11 ISO Standard`](http://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) a palavra-chave `volatile` serve apenas para uso para acesso ao hardware, não usá-lo para a comunicação [*inter-thread*](http://hpcquantlib.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/inter-thread-communication-using-lock-free-algorithms/). Para a comunicação *inter-thread*, a [`biblioteca padrão`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscc687y.aspx) prove o [`std::atomic<T>`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).